# Merge table columns by index using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, how can I merge columns `2` and `4` into a single column having `columnspan=2` using jquery?

```
<table id="Sample" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How exactly do you want it to appear? `<td>1</td><td colspan=2>2</td><td>3</td>` or `<td>1</td><td>3</td><td colspan=2>2</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var row = $("#Sample tr td");
        for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            var num1 = parseInt(row[i].innerHTML);
            var num2 = parseInt(row[i + 2].innerHTML);
            if (num1 == num2) {
                row[i].setAttribute("colspan", "2");
                row[i + 2].parentElement.removeChild(row[i + 2])
            }
        }


    });
```